# results doesn' t show all entries

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on a script that should show a list of my database entries so i can edit or delete them, but for some reason it only shows 4 out of 5 results from the database. If I enter a new entry into the database, it does show 5 results, but still not the 1 it didn't show before. This is pretty weird, cause my first try at making such a script did show all results. And I can't seem to find out what is wrong with it.

```
<?php

session_start(); 
include("important/passwords.php"); 
check_logged(); 

session_start();

include_once("includes/config.php");

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id"); 

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

?>

<html>
<head>    
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="divborder" style="width:600;">

    <table width='80%' border=0 bgcolor="#CCCCCC" bordercolordark="#666666" class="table">
        <tr bgcolor="#DFDFDF">
            <td>Datum</td>
            <td>Nieuws</td>
            <td>Update</td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {         
            echo "<tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>";
            echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>".$res['date']."</td>";
            echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>".$res['news']."</td>";    
            echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><a href=\"edit.php?id=$res[id]\">Aanpassen</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?id=$res[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Weet je zeker dat je dit nieuwsbericht wil verwijderen?')\">Verwijderen</a></td>";        
        }
        }
        ?>
                              <tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><form action="newsupload.php"><input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Voeg nieuws toe" class="upload"></form></td>
</tr>

    </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code i'm having that should make a new row in the table for every entry that is found. I don't know if it might have something to do with the fact that there are 2 messages without date entry in database, but on my previous try to get this working, it hadn't had any problems with showing both entries without were date is NULL.

Comment: In first snippet why using two while loops ie. `while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){` and `while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {`

Comment: + inside of `while` full html codes. what purpose ?

Comment: Try

    $date=$res['date'];
     echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>".$date."</td>";

And you have a plus

    <tr>

 before the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you code while looping same condition two bar remove one while loop

```
session_start(); 
include("important/passwords.php"); 
check_logged(); 

session_start();

include_once("includes/config.php");

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id"); 

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);


?>

<html>
<head>    
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="divborder" style="width:600;">

    <table width='80%' border=0 bgcolor="#CCCCCC" bordercolordark="#666666" class="table">
        <tr bgcolor="#DFDFDF">
            <td>Datum</td>
            <td>Nieuws</td>
            <td>Update</td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {         
            echo "<tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>";
            echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>".$res['date']."</td>";
            echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>".$res['news']."</td>";    
            echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><a href=\"edit.php?id=$res[id]\">Aanpassen</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?id=$res[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Weet je zeker dat je dit nieuwsbericht wil verwijderen?')\">Verwijderen</a></td>";        
        }
         ?>
                              <tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><form action="newsupload.php"><input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Voeg nieuws toe" class="upload"></form></td>
</tr>

    </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: THX! that did the trick! I tried to remove one while loop (must have been a part from my previous code I accidently copied over) after Haridarshan suggested it, but it didn't work, but i guess i messed up and erased some { i shouldn't have removed...

Comment: ah nvm, i forgot to erase one } :/ been with my into this code for too long, i guess, time for a break :p